# It's a natural thing of me

Tags: prepositions

Let's say Jason Statham is speaking to Arnold Schwarzenegger, then Jason Statham is asking a lil' consideration for his raspy voice, what is the correct preposition:

> Jason: forgive my voice, it's a lil bit raspy, it is a natural thing **of** me.

Or

> Jason: forgive my voice, it's a lil bit raspy, it is a natural thing **for** me.

Which is correct? Thx.

Comment: For is the correct preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments "for" is the correct preposition in this case. See this [link](https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/natural-for-or-natural-to/) – **except** that much of its content is so ungrammatical that I rather doubt its total veracity. It does cover various valid forms, however.  I've just selected a few examples of which prepositions can be used with "natural."

> **In 45% of cases natural *for* is used**
>
> > It's natural for my generation.
> >
> > This is natural for that group.
> >
> > They are a natural for the role.
>
> **In 22% of cases natural *to* is used.**
>
> > It seemed totally natural to me.
> >
> > But it feels very natural to me.
>
> **In 2% of cases natural *of* is used**

In fact, it's the most natural of things.

Comment: So what is the correct preposition exactly regarding to my question?

Comment: @JohnArvin, I'd say 'for'.